# Cosmos rating randomly shows up blank

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, class

I have a collectionView with an image, label and a cosmos view rating system in each cell. The cosmos rating is connected with firebase, where the ratings for each product is stored as the value to the users id. The problem is that the rating for a product randomly shows up as 0/blank whenever I rate a product many times. In most cases the rating updates to the correct new average rating, but sometimes it just shows blank, and is randomly fixed after i rate the product a few more times.

I have made a Product class which has the id, name, imageUrl and cosmos rating for each product:

```
class Product {
var category: String?
var name: String?
var imageUrl: String?
var rating: Double = 0
var id: String?

init(rawData: [String: AnyObject]) {
    id = rawData["id"] as? String
    name = rawData["name"] as? String
    imageUrl = rawData["imageUrl"] as? String
    if let ratingRaw = rawData["ratings"] as? [String: Int] {
        let values = Array(ratingRaw.values)
        var sum = 0
        for item in values {
            sum += item
        }

        rating = Double(sum) / Double(values.count)
    }

  }
}
```

It seems the problem lies in the product class, as I have tried to change the line of code `var rating: Double = 0` into `var rating: Double = 3`, which fixes the problem of the cosmos randomly showing up blank, but makes it randomly show up with 3 stars instead.

I then show the rating by instantiating the Product class in the vc:

```
var product: Product?
detailCosmosView.rating = product?.rating ?? 0
```

A user touches the cosmos rating and presses the submit button, this code updates the users rating:

```
    func updateRating(double: Double) {
    guard let userId = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    guard let category = product?.category, let id = product?.id else { return }
    Database.database().reference()
        .child("Categories")
        .child(category)
        .child(id)
        .child("ratings")
        .child(userId)
        .setValue(double)
}
```

There are seemingly no problems with this bit of code.

Comment: you should check your rawData . i think :  if let ratingRaw = rawData["ratings"] as? [String: Int] is not true . thats why your rating is not getting updated.

Comment: Hmm I see. Do you have any suggestions for what I can change it with?

Comment: i don't know about the stored data . you can put a breakpoint there and check why rate is null and it's not calculating